# response time for triggered Sends from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

We have configured triggered sends to send a considerably large email from Marketing Cloud.Every time a customer books a ticket,the website sends us the JSON payload and we build up the email with GTL and AMPscript. Number of emails being sent everyday are greater than 5k.The emails are going fine but our data visualization tool(Kibana) reports that the response time is huge.Also the team building the email says the response time of emails rendering is between 3 and 4 seconds which is ok by salesforce standards.

Also the flow of API call is that when a ticket is booked from website,it calls our service layer which in turn calls Marketing cloud.
So what and where could be the lag?How can we improve the performance?
Here is the screenshot from Kibana:

[image: Image showing the high Reposnse time]

Comment: You can improve the response time by using the async approach as described here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSends.htm

Comment: Thanks @Lukas Would you care to explain why sending asynchronous requests would make sense. I need to also check as to why synchronous calls were preferred in the first place.

Comment: I would expect the call being done significantly faster, as it does not to wait for the data to be processed. So your integration will be much more efficient, being able to send more requests to MC within same time.

Comment: I would also consider looking at the new transactional messaging routes in addition to async. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-api.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilising ASYNC API calls for triggered sends will increase the processing speed, and reduce the waiting time for your calls. I would expect the call being done significantly faster, as it does not to wait for the data to be processed. So your integration will be much more efficient, being able to send more requests to MC within same time.

Here is a sample payload for an ASYC request:

```
{
    "From": {
        "Address": "code@exacttarget.com",
        "Name": "Code@"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "example@example.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "Region": "West",
                "City": "Indianapolis",
                "State": "IN"
            }
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "RequestType": "ASYNC"
    }
}
```

You can also choose to use the transaction API released last year. It will not only reduce the response time of your API calls, but the emails will be sent much quicker than using classic triggered send definitions (even faster than those having priority set to *High*).

It is [documented here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-api.htm) - but it has some drawbacks worth observing, the major one being a lack of UI support for it, hence all the operations need to be performed using API.

Comment: It seems they are already using async method to make a call.Analyzing more in detail we see that there are many errors with the sending of emails
via SalesForce with the code SFMAIL_00001 (Remote error). We also see SFMAIL_00002 (Bad Request) errors but less.

The problem is that this sending of email fails and takes around 21 seconds to respond.